# How to make HP IR6 remote control work?

Tags: 10.04, hardware, lirc, hp-pavilion, peripherals

I've been using an HP Pavillion dv4-1430us laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 installed on it. I want to use the IR6 remote control that comes with the laptop on my Ubuntu. However, I've failed to do so after several attempts.

Could anyone please let me know about the complete and detailed procedure to get the remote working in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: I also had trouble with it, but now works out-of-the-box on 10.10 (on most machines).

Comment: P.S. make sure that the battery isn't depleted on the remote.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked on my HP-2140us:

1. Install the "Infrared Remote Control" app from the software center
2. If you haven't installed lirc before, you'll get a config screen; if the install completes without one, open a terminal and type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lirc`
3. Select ENE KB3926 as your receiver and None as your transmitter.
4. Open **Preferences > Infrafed Remote Control**, unlock and set the "IR Remote Control" settings to Manufacturer: HP, Model:TSGH-IR01
5. Press a few buttons on the remote and make sure they come up in the "Configuration Test" area.  If they do, you're done!

Finally, if you plan to use the remote with rhythmbox/totem/banshee/etc., you'll need to enable the lirc/remote control plugins in those apps.

**update**: you might need to restart after step 3

**update 2**  For Rhythmbox support add this in `~/.lircrc`:

```
begin
    prog = Rhythmbox
    button = PlayPause
    config = playpause
end

begin
    prog = Rhythmbox
    button = Skip
    config = next
end

begin
    prog = Rhythmbox
    button = Replay
    config = previous
end

begin
    prog = Rhythmbox
    button = VolUp
    config = volume_up
end

begin
    prog = Rhythmbox
    button = VolDown
    config = volume_down
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make my HP IR remote work only with rhythmbox:

1. Install `gnome-lirc-properties` using Software Center or `apt-get`
2. Edit the hardware.conf file

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/lirc/hardware.conf:
   ```

   add this text:

   ```
   #Chosen Remote Control
   REMOTE="ENE KB3926 B/C/D (ENE0100) CIR port"
   REMOTE_MODULES="lirc_dev lirc_ene0100"
   REMOTE_SOCKET=""
   REMOTE_LIRCD_CONF="/etc/lirc/lircd.conf"
   REMOTE_LIRCD_ARGS="-d /dev/lirc0"
   ```
3. Copy the configuration from [this URL](http://lirc.sourceforge.net/remotes/hp/HSTNN-PRO7)
4. Paste it to `lirc.conf` (open it like this)

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/lirc/lircd.conf
   ```
5. Reboot
6. Test if the IR is working

   In the terminal type the comand `irw` and press the remote control buttons to check.
7. In Rhythmbox go to **Edit > Plugins** and enable the LIRC plugin.

Comment: Thanks you Benjamin Gois...!! it's works great for my HP DV4-1213 LA with RC6 ir Hardware.
Operative system: kubuntu 10.10
If any have problems with a similar S.O. I can post my log's..